# How to convert bson to json effectively with mongo-go-driver?

Tags: json, mongodb, go, bson

I want to convert bson in [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) to json effectively.

I should take care to handle `NaN`, because `json.Marshal` fail if `NaN` exists in data.

For instance, I want to convert below bson data to json.

```golang
b, _ := bson.Marshal(bson.M{"a": []interface{}{math.NaN(), 0, 1}})
// How to convert b to json?
```

The below fails.

```golang
// decode
var decodedBson bson.M
bson.Unmarshal(b, &decodedBson)
_, err := json.Marshal(decodedBson)
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // it will be invoked
    // panic: json: unsupported value: NaN
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What specific problems are you facing?

Comment: So your question is specifically how to handle `math.NaN()` when marshaling JSON?

Comment: @Flimzy thanks, I added the code that I tried.

Comment: Yes, and I want to handle effectively. Even if the bson is deeply nested

Comment: You can unmarshal bson to interface{} and the marshal it to json. You may need to implement a custom decoder for Nan https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25721.

Comment: @georgeok: What do you mean by custom decoder? If you're decoding into `interface{}`, there's no opportunity to use a custom unmarshaler. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: I think if you try to json.Marshal the math.NaN the code will panic with `panic: json: unsupported value: NaN`. For example https://play.golang.org/p/0NAzLlXCUTm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the structure of your BSON, you can create a custom type that implements the `json.Marshaler` and `json.Unmarshaler` interfaces, and handles NaN as you wish. For example:

```
type maybeNaN struct{
    isNan  bool
    number float64
}

func (n maybeNaN) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if n.isNan {
        return []byte("null"), nil // Or whatever you want here
    }
    return json.Marshal(n.number)
}

func (n *maybeNan) UnmarshalJSON(p []byte) error {
    if string(p) == "NaN" {
        n.isNan = true
        return nil
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(p, &n.number)
}

type myStruct struct {
    someNumber maybeNaN `json:"someNumber" bson:"someNumber"`
    /* ... */
}
```

If you have an arbitrary structure of your BSON, your only option is to traverse the structure, using reflection, and convert any occurrences of NaN into a type (possibly a custom type as described above)